Barcode reader in C# on .NET 8 using ZXing
I am trying to write a C# class to read a barcode from a bmp file using ZXing.Net version 0.16.9.
This is the old way:
BarcodeReader br = new BarcodeReader();
string text = br.Decode(bmpFile).ToString(); 

but this is not working.

"but this is not working." How is it not working? Do you get any errors? Have you done anything to attempt to solve this on your own?

Copied straight from the project page on github
// create a barcode reader instance
BarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();
// load a bitmap
var barcodeBitmap = (Bitmap)Image.LoadFrom("C:\\sample-barcode-image.png");
// detect and decode the barcode inside the bitmap
var result = reader.Decode(barcodeBitmap);
// do something with the result
if (result != null)
{
   txtDecoderType.Text = result.BarcodeFormat.ToString();
   txtDecoderContent.Text = result.Text;
}

Note that the Decode()-function returns a result object instead of a simple string which likely causes the issue in your code.
